# How to set vim use tab instead of 4 whitespace?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

```
"(1)use 4 whitespace instead of tab
set cindent 
set smartindent 
set autoindent 
"set softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 expandtab smarttab

"(2)use tab instead of 4 whitespace
set cindent 
set smartindent 
set autoindent 
set tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 noexpandtab
```

The first settings is 4 whitespace.

Now my team use tab, the second setting work correctly in *.cpp *.h files, but still show 4 whitespace in *.py file.

I don't know why...?

Answer (score 1):

Check this blog entry: http://henry.precheur.org/vim/python.html

Creating a proper file in *ftplugin* folder will recognize the options for any python file.

Comment: This blog shows how to set python indent with 4 whitespace, which I already know. I want to know how to set python indent with tab...